# Calling time consuming method inside django view without using task queue

Tags: python, django

Whenever there is time consuming logic in [django](https://www.djangoproject.com/) view I run that as background task using [celery](http://www.celeryproject.org/) and return response.

```
from my_app.task import long_task
import json

def my_view(request):
    body = request.body
    body = json.loads(body)
    key = body['key']
    long_task.delay(key) # This will run in background
    return JsonResponse({'message': 'request submitted'})
```

Is there any way to achieve this behaviour to call long_task method without any background task queue like celery etc so I can quickly send response to user?

I guess there would be way to do this using operating system and python features.

Comment: I don't understand your question. The way to do this is with Celery. What is the problem with that?

Comment: I dont want to use celery or other task/job queue based approach. I am want to do this with operating system and python features

Comment: I don't know what "operating system and python features" would be here. The "python feature" that does this is Celery.

Comment: Operating system and python features like multiprocessing, multi threading

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're using Python >= 3.5 you can try asyncio in order to run a background task:

```
from my_app.task import long_task
import json
import asyncio
loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()


def my_view(request):
    body = request.body
    body = json.loads(body)
    key = body['key']
    arguments = [key]
    loop.run_in_executor(None, long_task, arguments)
    return JsonResponse({'message': 'request submitted'})
```

More info can be found [here](https://medium.com/@gauravbaliyan/a-good-use-of-asyncio-in-python-and-django-8aa7bc401e5f)

If you want to use asyncio on lower versions of Python (2.7 for example) you should be able to do that but keep in mind that is not included in standard core library and you need to install it.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. This will solve my requirement :) 
Dont know why someone downvoted my question :(

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can simply call a function directly in the view handler.

If this is a `Celery` task, you can call `apply`:

```
long_task.apply(args=[key])
```